# Pandas boxplot plotting incorrectly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create boxplots for all columns in a dataframe, but the resulting boxplot for the first column (Exon 8) has points that are not in my dataframe. It shows an outlier that shouldn't exist as well as a second boxplot on top of it. 
[image: Resulting image can be found here]

```py
print(ugh) 

              Exon 8      Exon 7      Exon 6   Exon 5      Exon 4   Exon 3      Exon 2   Exon 1   promoter 
   1062B    -6.850727 -10.426573  -7.121629 -9.072209  -5.144233 -8.749631  -7.464106 -8.294435 -5.907707
   1069T    -8.070629  -8.235831  -8.456142 -8.162655  -6.540471 -7.898194  -9.441525 -7.858809 -6.341495
   1078B    -8.351043  -8.629058  -9.052436 -7.652076  -5.822536 -6.629604  -8.810523 -5.912981 -6.051449
   1116B    -6.413303  -7.456374  -6.251024 -6.716293  -6.369380 -6.380853  -6.403044 -6.314320 -6.336989
   1131-1S  -6.237653  -9.621930  -6.160782 -8.447198  -6.310622 -7.476788  -6.296701 -6.970802 -6.410383
   1190T    -6.971004  -7.061738  -6.532381 -6.523190  -6.689861 -6.088864  -7.263789 -6.105003 -6.296208
   1197T    -9.718843  -6.836575  -9.386519 -6.294332  -9.097777 -5.948755 -10.271336 -5.982237 -6.647977
   540B    -10.818276  -7.881994 -11.038090 -7.353217 -11.711860 -6.696325 -11.860648 -6.556610 -5.982021


ugh.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Given your data:

- There isn't an issue that can be reproduced with the information provided
- If Jupyter is being used, Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs

  - Read the data back in

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Unnamed: 0     Exon 8     Exon 7     Exon 6    Exon 5     Exon 4    Exon 3     Exon 2    Exon 1  promoter
     1062B  -6.850727 -10.426573  -7.121629 -9.072209  -5.144233 -8.749631  -7.464106 -8.294435 -5.907707
     1069T  -8.070629  -8.235831  -8.456142 -8.162655  -6.540471 -7.898194  -9.441525 -7.858809 -6.341495
     1078B  -8.351043  -8.629058  -9.052436 -7.652076  -5.822536 -6.629604  -8.810523 -5.912981 -6.051449
     1116B  -6.413303  -7.456374  -6.251024 -6.716293  -6.369380 -6.380853  -6.403044 -6.314320 -6.336989
   1131-1S  -6.237653  -9.621930  -6.160782 -8.447198  -6.310622 -7.476788  -6.296701 -6.970802 -6.410383
     1190T  -6.971004  -7.061738  -6.532381 -6.523190  -6.689861 -6.088864  -7.263789 -6.105003 -6.296208
     1197T  -9.718843  -6.836575  -9.386519 -6.294332  -9.097777 -5.948755 -10.271336 -5.982237 -6.647977
      540B -10.818276  -7.881994 -11.038090 -7.353217 -11.711860 -6.696325 -11.860648 -6.556610 -5.982021


df.boxplot(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.ylim(-12, -3)
```

[image]

Comment: It turns out I just needed to clear a figure I previously created. Thank you!